# Socket.IO and ASCII

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, npm, socket.io

I've been trying to make a login system using Socket.io and everything is working so far.

Now whenever a user has a name containing a weird character for example 'ü' - he can't connect to server and I have no idea why, it just keeps reconnecting and failing. It's very weird but I do need it fixed, I tried removing the ascii charachters and that worked but I want users to be able to use characters like those.

Now whenever a user creates an account its data is logged in the database, now when I'm retrieving his or her data I use the following code,

```
socket.on('hash', function(hash) {  
    query('SELECT * FROM `registrants` WHERE `hash` = ' + pool.escape(hash), function(error, call) {
        if(error) return socket.disconnect();       

        connected = call[0];
    });     
});
```

Hash is provided by the cache from the user. It works fine, except when a name of a user, or any other data, contains a weird symbol/charachter.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Make sure your database character set and collation is set to utf8

Comment: @NikhilFadnis I did but nothing seems to have changed.